# Inhibiting a Flex text from being selected

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, mxml

On an Adobe Photoshop panel - which uses Adobe Flex 3 - I'd like some textual elements not to be selectable. If I have a text element like

```
<mx:Text id="t1" text="My text" x="4" width="200" textAlign="left"/>
```

I currently take care of that in an init() function using AS3 like this

```
t1.selectable = false;
```

My question is: Do I have to do that or is there an MXML way to do the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure it is just

```
<mx:Text id="t1" text="My text" x="4" width="200" textAlign="left" selectable="false" />
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS02f7d8d4857b1677-165a04e1126951a2d98-7fe4.html